# Can I ask again for facebook permissions after the user denied?

Tags: facebook, ios6

Using iOS 6 facebook SDK native dialogues I wish to ask for facebook permissions a second time after the user denied the first time.
I am using:

```
[[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

On the iOS 6 simulator it works and it asks again but on a device it does not.
any work arounds beside removing the facebook app at the facebook site?

Comment: Does the device have the native Facebook app installed?

Comment: I don't wish to direct him to the facebook app
is there a programatic solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can try reauthorizeWithPermissions:behavior:completionHandler:

```
- (void)reauthorizeWithPermissions:(NSArray*)permissions behavior:(FBSessionLoginBehavior)behavior completionHandler:(FBSessionReauthorizeResultHandler)handler __attribute__((deprecated));
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.1/class/FBSession#reauthorizeWithPermissions%3Abehavior%3AcompletionHandler%3A

Comment: is it working for you on an ios 6 device with a logged in facebook account? my problem is that it works on simulator but not on device